# Getting a TargetParameterCountException while implement log4net csv mapping

Tags: c#, csv, log4net

I'm implementing csv logging output using log4net based upon Steven Padfield's blog http://element533.blogspot.com/2010/05/writing-to-csv-using-log4net.html.
I simply copied and pasted the CSVPattern class into my code and created classes to pass into into CSVPattern based upon a logging event. The problem I'm having is that when my object goes through the Format method, I'm getting a System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException.

My object lass passed to the CSVPatternLayout.cs is as follows:

```
public class EmailCSVLog
{
    public string EmailTo { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }       
}
```

The Web.Config entry for the CSVFileAppender is as follows:

```
<appender name="CsvFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="logs\log.csv"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <layout type=" ESI_Admin.Utility.CsvPatternLayout">
    <header value="DateTime,Level,To,From,Subject&#13;&#10;" />
    <conversionPattern value="%date{M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss.fff}%newfield%level%newfield%property{To}%newfield%property{From}%newfie     ld%property{Subject}%endrow" />
  </layout>
```

I don't see any reason for a parameter mismatched. If anyone has ideas as to why the error is being thrown, I'm all ears.

Comment: Please post your copied CSVPattern class and the exception details. I suggest you read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property in `EmailCSVLog` is called `EmailTo` but in the appender `conversionPattern` it's being referenced as `To` (I.E. `%property{To}`)